# Simple second variation

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I am new to calculus of variation and try to understand some simple special cases. In particular, what is the second variation for a functional
$$J[y]=\int_{a}^{b} F(x, y(x)) dx$$
**without** the $y'(x)$ term in $F$? Is it
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} \left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} F(x,y(x))\right] \cdot \left[y(x)\right]^2 dx
$$
or am I missing something trivial? I got the above formula from Section 5 in Gelfand and Fomin's textbook (see screenshot attached) and simply take out the second and third terms inside the integral in Equation (9). [image]

Any hint is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is correct, but you need to replace $y^2$ with the squared of the variation instead, i.e. $h^2$ if you're using the notation from the screenshot you attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Premise**: this [MathOverflow Q&A on functional derivatives on Banach spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355279/functional-derivatives-on-banach-spaces/355984#355984) and [this one on higher order functional derivatives](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353288/higher-order-functional-derivatives/355408#355408) may be useful.

**Answer**. Second and higher order variations may be defined in the most general way as follows
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\delta^n}{\delta h_1 \delta h_2\cdots\delta h_n}J[y] &\triangleq  \frac{\partial^n}{\partial \varepsilon_1 \partial \varepsilon_2\cdots\partial \varepsilon_n}J[y+\varepsilon_1 h_1 + \varepsilon_2 h_2+\ldots + \varepsilon_n h_n]\bigg|_{\varepsilon_i =0\; i=1,\ldots,n}.
\end{split}
$$
If we can choose $h_i =h $ and $\varepsilon_i =\varepsilon$ for all $i = 1,\ldots, n$ we have the following simplified formulation:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\delta^n}{\delta h^n }J[y] &\triangleq  \frac{\partial^n}{\partial \varepsilon^n }J[y+\varepsilon h]\bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0}\\
\end{split}
$$
Be it noted that the second form of $n$-variation is particularly suited to deal with integral type functionals $J$ as it happens in the case under examination: the former form is however more general in that it explicitly show the multilinearity of the higher variation functional and it is thus applicable to the case where the variations $h_1, \ldots, h_n$ are not functions but more generally generalized functions.
For $n=2$, by applying the latter definition to the very special form of the functional $J[y]$ at hand, we have
$$
\frac{\delta^2}{\delta h^2 }J[y](h) = \int\limits_a^b \left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} F(x,y)\right] |h(x)|^2\operatorname{d\!}{x}
$$
Note that including the factor $1/2$ in the definition of the second variation is a notational convention adopted by Gel'fand and Fomin in their textbook: Giaquinta and Hildebrandt do not follow this convention in their two volume monograph.